# Can't find the 'Built-in Example Applications'

Tags: spotify

In the spotify developer's [integration guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#built-inexampleapplications), there's a chapter about 'Built-in Example Applications'. I can't find any of these two applications (Tabs & Api). There are links to the application URI that aren't working and no files to download like TutorialApp.zip.
Did anyone find these two resources ?
By the way, Merry christmas !!

Comment: They seem to be unavailable at the moment. Take a look at this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353471/spotify-apps-api-any-more-documentation) to get access to the source code of some of the built-in apps.

Comment: Thanks !! resources.zip seems to contain much more than expected !!

Answer (score 1):

These examples have been removed from the client. We will include more in-depth tutorials on our developer website; developer.spotify.com