# Cant see example apps?

Tags: spotify

So I wanted to look at the example applications "tabs" and "api".

But all I see is "Sorry, I could not find this app"

and then two sections with the text:

metadataStarted
URI: spotify:app:tabs

metadataFailed
URI: spotify:app:tabs
Error: appNotFound

So, how could those apps not be found? As I understand they should be there from thestart?

Comment: See previous question [Can't find built-in example applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628566/cant-find-the-built-in-example-applications/ "Can't find the built-in example applications")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be unavailable at the moment. Take a look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353471/spotify-apps-api-any-more-documentation) where you can get some useful resources.