# How I do use pagination in Spotify Apps

Tags: spotify

How I do create the elements like pagination, crossovers and pagination easily as mentioned in the design page 
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/design/#applicationicon

Is there any external js/css that can be used and how can I download/use them? There is no written documentation about them.

Answer (score 0):

Read this question, this is how to use the Spotify pagniation/slider plugin.

[How to create a "carousel"-like widget in spotify apps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850514/how-to-create-a-carousel-like-widget-in-spotify-apps-api)