# What data should I pass to Spotify App to make pagination work?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I've got a Spotify app working with various implementations of views and models, but I can't get pager to work. The example here:
 [How to create a "carousel"-like widget in spotify apps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850514/how-to-create-a-carousel-like-widget-in-spotify-apps-api) 
throws this error when you try to click on the next button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'logClientEvent'

I've tried passing playlists and tracks to `p.Pager`, but without any success.

Also, I notice that there's nothing in the API docs about Pager - is it even available to the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just experienced the same thing and referred it to one of their developers (@possan).

In the mean time, stub out the failing call:

```
sp.core.logClientEvent = sp.core.logClientEvent || function(){}
```