# Spotify pagination controls for app API 1.0

Tags: spotify

I am missing the views and stylesheets for pagination in the documentation for Spotify App API 1.0. Where can I get the pagination controls from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Spotify API 0.X there was a component called `Pager` to accomplish that (see [How to create a "carousel"-like widget in spotify apps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850514/how-to-create-a-carousel-like-widget-in-spotify-apps-api)). However, that component had never been publicly documented, and only the "What's New" page made use of it.

In the API 1.0 that component has finally been deprecated.